# Fields on tables linked to Access 2010 from Postgres not becoming Memo?

Tags: postgresql, ms-access, odbc

I have a repeating problem that just feels so basic yet I cannot solve it nor can I find a solution online.  Really hoping someone has something simple.

I have multiple situations where I have relatively large tables stores in Postgres (v8.4) and I want to be able to easily display them for my testers to review.  The tables always have character varying fields that go well beyond the 255 max that Access wants to display in a Text field; it should become a Memo field.  The data also has every possible separator imaginable already in it (tab, carriage return, semi colon, pipe, etc) and extracting it to Excel or such will never work smoothly.  The easiest thing WOULD be using ODBC to link the table into an Access DB and viewing it there ... except that when I link or import, Access translates the field to Text.  I've tried settings on the ODBC, but nothing can get those Fields to be Memo.

I'll take a way to extract to Excel cleaner, to view it in Access better .. just anything that gets me the entire table in a low level user friendly way to consistently get a table like that to a place they can review it.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Better late than never..

I just ran into this problems with Access 2010 and Postgres 9.1. I found a setting in the Postgres ODBC driver settings that you have to change. In the ODBC Data Source Administrator, select the datasource that you setup and click the 'Configure...' button.

[image: Driver setup screenshot]

Click the 'Datasources' button.

[image: Advanced options screenshot]

Uncheck the 'Text as LongVarChar' checkbox

In Access, you may have to delete the linked tables and re-add them. I tried relinking and one table updated properly and one did not. After deleting are re-adding, I had both working.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting [`text`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-character.html) datatype for all columns that you want to have `Memo` Data Type. I checked that with PostgreSQL 9.0 (64 bit), [psqlodbc_09_00_0310](http://www.postgresql.org/ftp/odbc/versions/msi/) (32 bit, so I created User DSN under `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe`) and as I see all columns wit text type become Memo, as opposite to `characted(6)` column that has Text Data Type in Access.

Comment: OK, I did that before and still got the "too large" error, so I guess I didn't check the field type.  That does, in fact, translate them to Memo fields ... but linking to the table still gets a Save Failure "Could not save the object".  I'm reviewing my data now, but it'll take a while to slog through the mess and see if/where any failures occurred.